# Class Inheritance and Ruby Modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've decided to break up by Rails application into different modules for clarity, and as a part of this I'd like each module to have its own ApplicationController.  So I went through and defined an application controller for each module like so:

```
module Login
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

Then I'd create a different controller in the login module:

```
module Login
  class HomeController < ApplicationController

  end
end
```

My expectation was that this would first search the Login module for the application controller, but from what I'm seeing it's actually inheriting the global application controller (any declarations I make in Login::ApplicationController aren't picked up).  I've searched around for some information on this, but haven't been able to figure out why it is using the ApplicationController in the top level name space and not the one in Login.   It works just fine having HomeController inherit from Login::ApplicationController, but I'd like to learn why it doesn't work without the Login:: prefix for the future.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, what are the first few classes output when you run `Login::HomeController.ancestors` from rails console?

Comment: Interesting, Login::ApplicationController is in fact listed there but before_filters and other calls don't seem to be run from it>

Comment: Could you paste in the code of the controllers and give some examples of things that aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
module Login
  class HomeController < Login::ApplicationController

  end
end
```

Comment: As I said, I figured out that this is the solution but it doesn't seem intuitive to me.  Why doesn't ruby start searching within the current module?

Comment: See above comment, seems that Ruby does in fact search in the current module